# C# Loops, the input value of a textbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I'm newbie here and I am confuse about C#.

Here is the question I must get the value that the user input on a textbox and then loop the value that the textbox have, example textbox have 5 the answer will be on label and it must be 12345.

it does not loop, when i execute the program it will just result the input value on the textbox

```
int IntLoop;
for (IntLoop = 0; IntLoop <= Convert.ToInt32(TxtEvaluate.Text); IntLoop++)
{
    LblLoop.Text = IntLoop.ToString();
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? It's not so clear from your question - what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: it does not loop, when i execute the program it will just result the input value on the textbox,

Comment: If the value of `TxtEvaluate.Text` is 7 what do you expect to be assigned to `LblLoop.Text`?

Answer (score 4):

Try **appending** the loop's iterator to your textbox using `+=`:

```
 LblLoop.Text = string.Empty;
 for (int IntLoop = 1; IntLoop <= Convert.ToInt32(TxtEvaluate.Text); IntLoop++)
 {
     LblLoop.Text += IntLoop.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions which you do not understand. That's what the comment section is for.

Comment: @Koby: the question is pretty obvious from the explanation and code.

Comment: I upvoted since this is what the OP was looking for, and edited your answer. Hope you don't mind.